# getting user details using firebase auth where condition is multiple phoneNumbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to retrieve users using phoneNumber where phoneNumber is multiple I would say an array of phoneNumber I want to get the users response using this. I only know how to retrieve using a single number.i have created this code and when I pass individual numbers it works but I don't know how to execute for an array of phonNumbers.

```
const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {
  return auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).catch(() => {
    return ;
  });
};

const userRecords = await Promise.all([getAuth('+915555555555'), getAuth('+916666445555')]);
console.log(userRecords)
```

and I have an array of phoneNumbers that is

```
['+915555555555','+916666445555','+917778886655',+91555598668']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {
  return auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).catch(() => {
    return ;
  });
};

const userRecords = await Promise.all(
    phoneNumber.map(phNo => {
      return getAuth(phNo);
    }),
  );
console.log(userRecords)
```

here phoneNumber is an array where number is stored.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. You can use `.map` to iterate and return array of promises to `Promise.all`. something like this

```
const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {
  return auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).catch(() => {
    return ;
  });
};

async function getAll() {
   const userRecords = await Promise.all(['+915555555555','+916666445555','+917778886655','+91555598668'].map(phNo => getAuth(phNo)));
   return userRecords;
}
```

The async wrapping is just for executing it. You don't need it if you are putting this code in async function.

Comment: in this, there is a problem of  scope and i have to use the userRecord and print it in excel file where data is also coming from firebase

Comment: sorry didn't really get the scope part. You mean you need to use `userRecords` variable somewhere else?

Comment: yes, I have tried the above method but I got the scope issue.

Comment: I have converted that to a function and returned the value. now you can call this function as a normal async function and use the returned value of `userRecords`

Comment: can you tell me one thing when i am running this code it doesn't exit it continuously runs if i use this user auth code

Comment: you mean it doesn't exit? you could manually do `process.exit(0);` at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206204/discussion-between-amarjeet-kumar-singh-and-ashish-modi).

Comment: i have used the process.exit(0); at the end of the program it closes the process but it didn't print or create excel file do you know any other way. Thanks